# What is the D3D12 equivalent of Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION)?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-9, directx-12

So I am currently coding a D3D12 engine and was wondering what the D3D12 equivalent of this D3D9 function is ?

```
direct3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [Direct3D Game VS Templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/) for how the basic render loop and device creation works for Direct3D 12. That said, it seems like you are trying to port from Direct3D 9 directly to Direct3D 12 which is ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent is D3D12CreateDevice. It's used for example like this:

```
hr = D3D12CreateDevice( adapter, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0, IID_PPV_ARGS( &device ) );
```

Comment: The closest thing would probably be the dxgi factory, not the device.

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinct equivalent, the closest could be `CreateDXGIFactory` to me, as it is the access point to adapters and outputs.

But if you are asking that kind of question, d3d12 is not for you. Unless you are already a d3d11 more than expert everyday user working on a triple A kind graphic engine, d3d12 is not what you are looking for. It is better to stick to d3d11.